# Writing from a MemoryStream to FileStream corrupts the data

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to write a byte array to a file, which, I would assume, should be simple. I'm trying to use a `MemoryStream` to get the `byte()` and copy it to the `FileStream`. See my code below.

```
If File.Exists(path) Then
    Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(path)
    Do While sr.Peek() >= 0
        sr.Read()
    Loop
    sr.Close()

Else
    res = GetInfo(timeout, bytes)
    If res = 0 Then
        Dim s As Stream = New FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
        Dim stream As New MemoryStream(bytes)

        stream.CopyTo(s)
        stream.Dispose()

       ' do other stuff
    End If
End If
```

It compiles fine but when I check the written file, the data is corrupted and looks like:

```
Í¤I¶µ&Ôœ¸Šíd9ïè´5ì#~¿g•ø9£ÓÙ=¸Š€8j]f½’˜»4e18+jš³VÀú¸àc?ê
```

Other things I've tried:

- Using a `StreamWriter`. It works fine, however, I read here that it should only be used for `String`s and not `byte`s, so I'm not using it.
- Using `FileStream.Write` method, the data is corrupted again
- Using `MemoryStream.WriteTo` method, the data is corrupted again

The byte array looks like:

```
105
203
13
47
...
```

My data is actually a `Byte()` but gets corrupted with `Byte` methods and works with the `String` method, so it's kind of confusing. Am I missing a step or something?

Comment: is it that you want to write the memory stream to disk ?

Comment: You are writing to a text file and `StreamWriter` is the right way to do it.

Comment: What do you expect to see in the file? Its impossible for us to guess what corruption has ocurred or even *if* corruption has occurred based on what you've given us. You need to give us the input, ie the byte array, that you are trying to save for us to have a hope of seeing what is going wrong.

Comment: if used a memorystream,u can write things like pictures and other similar stuff

Comment: @Chris edited. Thanks.

Comment: That's up to you, we cannot decide that for you. What do the bytes represent? If they represent text, then you write them use `StreamWriter` to a text file. If they represent binary data (e.g. image, dll, etc...) then you write them to a binary file and cannot use `StreamWriter`.

Comment: When you are viewing your file what text encoding are you using? And also why are you seemingly viewing it in a text editor anyway rather than a hex editor or something designed for viewing binary data? It would probably be more helpful if you told us what the byte values in your saved file were rather than what the text representation of those bytes was, if nothing else because not all bytes are printable characters.

Comment: @Chris, you were right. I shouldn't have been trying to view the file in the text editor anyway. When I tried to read the very same file using `File.ReadAllBytes` I get the data unchanged. Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you're expecting string values from your byte array, rather than the actual byte data.

Answer (score 2):

If your memory stream can read the file/byte properly,then it can write it to !

```
 Dim bytes as Byte() = New Byte(memoryStream.length)
 filestream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
 ms.Close
```

If it is just some textual data,do this :

```
 IO.File.WriteAllText("pathhere","String Here")
```

To read the stream,do this :

```
 Using ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
 Using file As FileStream = New FileStream("filePath", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim bytes As Byte() = New Byte(file.Length - 1) {}
        file.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(file.Length))
        ms.Write(bytes, 0, CInt(file.Length))
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Tried WriteTo too, unfortunately same corrupted data.

Comment: is it some image that you want to write or what ?

Comment: it is configuration data for a device, the written byte will be read and used as bytes again.

Comment: the edit will do the same as before....i guess u are getting it wrong ... Are you using any sort of encryption somewhere like base64 encryption or so ?

Comment: Yes, in the question I mentioned I tried `filestream.Write` too. I'm not using any encryption. Something is definitely wrong but can't figure out what. Thank you.

Comment: yes , and i assume the wrong is that you are reading some textual data as byte array